# Update Query Result in JPA

Tags: jpa, persistence

I have the code below which will query an entity and set a random number:

```
    EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    Profile user = null;
    Query q = null;
    try{
        q = em.createNamedQuery("Profile.getRandomProfile");
        q.setParameter("random", Math.random());
        q.setMaxResults(1);
        user = (Profile) q.getSingleResult();

        user.setRandom( Math.random() );

    } catch(NoResultException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I thought doing so will update random property of profile. Why isn't it updated? How to update the random property?

Comment: You should make sure the above code is executed inside a transaction. How to do that depends on your environment (EJB container? Spring? Basic application?).

Comment: Basic application. It works now, as suggested by James.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to begin and commit a transaction around your changes.

See,

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Transactions

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving it back to the Database. You should use merge() method one EntityManager to update within transactions

Comment: No, he shouldn't have to do that. JPA automatically makes changes to attached entities persistent, and automatically flushed before committing the transaction.